# Цепочное освобождение объектов

Tags: c#, .net, interop

Все объекты являются неуправляемыми за исключением некоторых типов.

Принцип наследования:

```
public interface IVlcObject // Главный обобщенный интерфейс
{
    void Release();
    void DeleteLater(object sender, ref IVlcObject obj);
}
```

Наследником интерфейса является абстрактный класс, который является в свою очередь обобщенным классом для всех остальных неуправляемых объектов:

```
internal abstract class VlcObject<TDeleter> : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid, IVlcObject where TDeleter : Delegate
{
    private readonly VlcLibrary _libVlc;
    private readonly VlcLibrary _libVlcCore;
    protected readonly TDeleter Deleter;

    protected VlcObject() : base(true)
    {
        _libVlcCore = WinApi.LoadLibrary(Factory.LibVlcCorePath);
        _libVlc = WinApi.LoadLibrary(Factory.LibVlcPath);
        Deleter = ResolveVlc<TDeleter>();
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        _libVlc.Close();
        _libVlcCore.Close();
        bool result = _libVlc.IsClosed && _libVlcCore.IsClosed;
        return result;
    }

    internal static bool CheckAttr<TDelegate>(out string procName) where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        Type typeData = typeof(TDelegate);
        object[] attributes = typeData.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CFuncAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length <= 0)
        {
            procName = string.Empty;
            return false;
        }
        procName = ((CFuncAttribute)attributes[0])?.Function;
        return true;
    }


    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    protected TDelegate ResolveVlc<TDelegate>() where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        if (CheckAttr<TDelegate>(out string name))
        {
            return ResolveVlc<TDelegate>(name);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Delegate with param type cannot be used for extract procedure name! Please see another overload.");
    }

    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    protected TDelegate ResolveVlcCore<TDelegate>() where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        Factory.Log();
        if (CheckAttr<TDelegate>(out string name))
        {
            return ResolveVlcCore<TDelegate>(name);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Delegate with param type cannot be used for extract procedure name! Please see another overload.");
    }


    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    protected TDelegate ResolveVlc<TDelegate>(string name) where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        return _libVlc.Resolve<TDelegate>(name);
    }


    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    protected TDelegate ResolveVlcCore<TDelegate>(string name) where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        return _libVlcCore.Resolve<TDelegate>(name);
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        Close();
    }

    public void DeleteLater(object sender, ref IVlcObject obj)
    {
        ((VlcInstance) obj).VlcObjects.Remove(DangerousGetHandle());
        ((VlcInstance) obj).DoDeleteLater -= DeleteLater;
        Release();
    }
}
```

Далее наследники перегружают метод `ReleaseHandle` и сами производят вызов `TDeleter` с `Handle`'om которым владеют, далее приведу один из классов, который бы как мне хотелось при освобождении уничтожал все объекты которые ссылались на него, но не были освобождены, а те объекты которые ссылались на данный объект, и были уничтожены самостоятельно, вызывали бы какой-то метод и убирали бы себя из списка объектов подлежащих утилизации при уничтожении объекта на который сослались.

Т.е. хотелось бы реализовать что-то вроде `DeleteLater` в `Qt`.

Как мне показалось то возможно вот такое решение будет нормальным, но может есть какие-то другие способы реализовать все это дело, да так что бы например не было проблем с много-поточным обращением.

Ниже приведен интерфейс который возвращается вместо самого объекта для работы с ним:

```
public interface IVlcInstance :
                 IVlcObject // используем обобщенный интерфейс
{
    ...
}
```

Наследник данного интерфейса, а так же объект который может создавать другие объекты:

```
internal delegate void RemoveSelfOnDestroy(object sender, ref IVlcObject obj);

internal class VlcInstance : VlcObject<libvlc_release>, IVlcInstance
{
    protected internal readonly Dictionary<IntPtr, IVlcObject> VlcObjects;

    internal event RemoveSelfOnDestroy DoDeleteLater;

    protected VlcInstance()
    {
        Factory.Log();
        VlcObjects = new Dictionary<IntPtr, IVlcObject>();
    }

    public LibVlcExitHandler ExitHandler
    {
        set => SetExitHandler(value);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IVlcMediaPlayer CreatePlayer()
    {
        VlcMediaPlayer player = ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_player_new>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle());
        if (!CheckInvalidAndRelease(ref player))
        {
            return player;
        }

        VlcObjects.Add(player.DangerousGetHandle(), player);
        DoDeleteLater += player.DeleteLater;
        return player;
    }

    public IVlcMedia OpenMedia(Uri mrl)
    {
        VlcMedia media = mrl.IsLoopback
            ? ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_new_path>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle(), mrl.ToString())
            : ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_new_location>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle(), mrl.ToString());

        if (!CheckInvalidAndRelease(ref media))
        {
            return media;
        }

        VlcObjects.Add(media.DangerousGetHandle(), media);
        DoDeleteLater += media.DeleteLater;
        return media;
    }

    public IVlcMedia OpenMedia(string path)
    {
        VlcMedia media = ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_new_path>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle(), path);
        if (!CheckInvalidAndRelease(ref media)) return media;
        VlcObjects.Add(media.DangerousGetHandle(), media);
        DoDeleteLater += media.DeleteLater;
        return media;

    }

    public IVlcMedia OpenMedia(FileInfo file)
    {
        VlcMedia media = ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_new_path>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle(), file.FullName);
        if (!CheckInvalidAndRelease(ref media)) return media;
        VlcObjects.Add(media.DangerousGetHandle(), media);
        DoDeleteLater += media.DeleteLater;
        return media;

    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private static bool CheckInvalidAndRelease<TVlcObject>(ref TVlcObject obj) where TVlcObject : IVlcObject
    {
        if (!((SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid) (IVlcObject) obj).IsInvalid) return true;
        obj.Release();
        obj = default;
        return false;
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        IVlcObject self = this;
        OnDeleteLater(ref self);
        Deleter.Invoke(DangerousGetHandle());
        return base.ReleaseHandle();
    }

    private void SetExitHandler(LibVlcExitHandler handler)
    {
        ResolveVlc<libvlc_set_exit_handler>().Invoke(DangerousGetHandle(), handler, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDeleteLater(ref IVlcObject obj)
    {
        DoDeleteLater?.Invoke(this, ref obj);
    }
}
```

Таким образом все связанные объекты уничтожаются, но может есть более удобный способ такое провернуть?

Comment: Нельзя делать `DangerousGetHandle()` и передавать его в нативный код! Если в этот момент кто-то вызовет `Close()` - будет ошибка. Передавайте делегатам непосредственно SafeHandle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы уверены, что ваша задача - именно уничтожить все объекты перед выгрузкой библиотеки, а не отложить выгрузку библиотеки до момента уничтожения всех объектов?

Второе делается куда более просто при помощи `DangerousAddRef`/`DangerousRelease`:

```
abstract class VlcObject : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeHandle parent;

    public void SetParent(SafeHandle newParent) {
        bool success = false;

        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try {
            if (newParent != null) newParent.DangerousAddRef(ref success);
            if (parent != null) parent.DangerousRelease();
        } finally {
            if (success)
                parent = newParent;
            else
                parent = null;
        }
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    protected virtual bool ReleaseHandle() {
        if (parent != null) parent.DangerousRelease();
        parent = null;
        return true;
    }
}

// ...

public IVlcMediaPlayer CreatePlayer() {
    VlcMediaPlayer player = ResolveVlc<libvlc_media_player_new>().Invoke(this);
    player.SetParent(this);
    return player;
}
```

Comment: Библиотека не выгружается пока присутствует хоть один живой объект ссылающийся на нее. А вариант с передачей `SafeHandle` вместо `IntPtr` весьма занимателен, но работает почему-то медленнее обычного голого указателя...

Comment: @LLENN он работает медленнее потому что делает DangerousAddRef и DangerousRelease внутрях. Но эти вызовы **нужно** делать, иначе быть ошибке.

Comment: Работает как часы! Единственное что пришлось изменить немного логику всех классов, а так же наследовать интерфейс от `IDisposable` для доступа к `Dispose` методу.

Answer (score 4):

По моему, ничего более интересного придумать нельзя.

Разве что заменить метод, который вызывает порожденный объект у родителя, что бы обозначить, что произошло удаление на `событие`.

Т.е `Родитель` создает `дочерний` объект и перед отправкой этого объекта наружу подписывается на какое-нибудь событие удаления.

Если `дочерний` объект удаляется, то вызывается перед смертью событие и `родитель` удаляет у себя ссылку на этот объект.

По моему, так более красивее и естественно будет выглядеть. И порожденному объекту в этом случае не нужно будет хранить ссылку на родителя, что бы вызвать метод у родителя, что бы уведомить об удалении.

В первом листинге, вроде, вы что-то делаете похожее на это, так как я вижу удаление из словаря объектов, однако, во втором листинге, где вы хотите дать такое поведение, я не вижу этого.

P.S Код смотрел бегло.